# Running SOLR on a desktop application

Tags: java, apache, solr, jetty, solr4

**while running solr 4.10.3 solr\examples  i ran following command on cmd java -jar start.jar

**after this when i go on http://localhost:8983/ i got this error
Error 404 - Not Found.
No context on this server matched or handled this request.
Contexts known to this server are:
/solr ---> o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/solr,null},D:\solr-4.10.3\exampleD:/solr-4.10.3/example/webapps/solr.war**

Answer (score 0):

try http://localhost:8983/solr. By this you are provding the web application within which it might need to find index.* i.e. welcome file.

Comment: still not working got this error            HTTP ERROR: 404

Problem accessing /solr/. Reason:

    Not Found
Powered by Jetty://

Comment: is your jetty server up and running? Do you see any exception in jetty log?